# Is there an R function to merge two data frames based on two columns separately matching to the same column?

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I would like to two populate values (`"VAL"`) based on one of two columns separately(`"VALA"`,`"VALB"`).

```
# Data 
DF1 <- data.frame("colA" = rep(c("A","B"), 6),
                  "colB" = rep(c("C","D","E"), 4))

DF2 <- data.frame("colC" = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                  "VAL" = 1:5)

# three join calls     
tmp1 <- left_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("colA"="colC"))
names(tmp1)[3] <-  "VALA"

tmp2 <- left_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("colB"="colC"))
names(tmp2)[3] <-  "VALB"

left_join(tmp1, tmp2, by=c("colA", "colB"))

#    colA colB VALA VALB
# 1     A    C    1    3
# 2     A    C    1    3
# 3     B    D    2    4
# 4     B    D    2    4
# 5     A    E    1    5
# 6     A    E    1    5
# 7     B    C    2    3
# 8     B    C    2    3
# 9     A    D    1    4
# 10    A    D    1    4
# 11    B    E    2    5
# 12    B    E    2    5
# 13    A    C    1    3
# 14    A    C    1    3
# 15    B    D    2    4
# 16    B    D    2    4
# 17    A    E    1    5
# 18    A    E    1    5
# 19    B    C    2    3
# 20    B    C    2    3
# 21    A    D    1    4
# 22    A    D    1    4
# 23    B    E    2    5
# 24    B    E    2    5
```

Why does the last operation give 24 rows as output instead of expected 12?

Is there any possibility to achieve the same expected out in the most elegant way(instead of 3 join operations)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to find the corresponding value and `cbind` the resluting columns.

```
cbind(DF1, VALA=DF2$VAL[match(DF1$colA, DF2$colC)],
  VALB=DF2$VAL[match(DF1$colB, DF2$colC)])
   colA colB VALA VALB
#1     A    C    1    3
#2     B    D    2    4
#3     A    E    1    5
#4     B    C    2    3
#5     A    D    1    4
#6     B    E    2    5
#7     A    C    1    3
#8     B    D    2    4
#9     A    E    1    5
#10    B    C    2    3
#11    A    D    1    4
#12    B    E    2    5
```

or use names:

```
x <- setNames(DF2$VAL, DF2$colC)
cbind(DF1, VALA=x[DF1$colA], VALB=x[DF1$colB])
```

and in case for many columns using `match` inside `lapply`

```
cbind(DF1, setNames(lapply(DF1, function(x) DF2$VAL[match(x, DF2$colC)]),
 sub("col", "VAL", names(DF1))))
#   colA colB VALA VALB
#1     A    C    1    3
#2     B    D    2    4
#3     A    E    1    5
#4     B    C    2    3
#5     A    D    1    4
#6     B    E    2    5
#7     A    C    1    3
#8     B    D    2    4
#9     A    E    1    5
#10    B    C    2    3
#11    A    D    1    4
#12    B    E    2    5
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the `match` possibility, could this be achieved using `join*` functions?

Comment: Secondly, could this be extended to multiple columns? `... DF2[match(DF1$colA, DF2$colC), c(VAL1, VAL2)]...` I guess, yes, isn't it? Though I am not sure of assigning two column names (`VALA1`, `VALA2`)

Comment: Could you please explain the last operation and also include the output you get? I am getting an unexpected output.

Comment: The last one is the same like the first one but going to each column of `DF1` using `lapply`.

Comment: I meant how to extend the operation to multiple columns from `DF2`? Assuming, there are two columns `VAL1`, `VAL2` instead of `VAL` alone in `DF2`.

Comment: Can you give an example dataset and expected output?

Comment: Replacing `DF2` with `DF2 <- data.frame("colC" = c("A","B","C","D","E"), "VAL1" = sample(1:5,5), "VAL2" = sample(1:5,5))`. The matching for one operation as: `DF2[match(DF1$colA, DF2$colC), c("VAL1", "VAL2")]`, the second one as `DF2[match(DF1$colB, DF2$colC), c("VAL1", "VAL2")]` The expected should contain these four columns combined inaddition to the original columns.

Comment: Without naming try: `cbind(DF1, lapply(DF1, function(x) DF2[match(x, DF2$colC),-1]))`

Comment: I formulated it. Thanks for saying naming is not feasible simultaneously with the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine `left_join` after one another using `%>%` and define its suffixes.

```
DF1 <- DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, c("colA" = "colC")) %>%
  left_join(DF2, c("colB" = "colC"), 
            suffix = c ("A", "B"))

> DF1
   colA colB VALA VALB
1     A    C    1    3
2     B    D    2    4
3     A    E    1    5
4     B    C    2    3
5     A    D    1    4
6     B    E    2    5
7     A    C    1    3
8     B    D    2    4
9     A    E    1    5
10    B    C    2    3
11    A    D    1    4
12    B    E    2    5
```